# Crontab using python venv

Tags: python, cron

I'm trying to execute a python code in a daily basis. To achieve this, i'm using cron tab on mac os, using a virtual enviroment. To activate it, i've created the following cron tab statement:

7 23 * * * /Users/dvilches/Desktop/Python/NewProject/env/bin/python /Users/dvilches/Desktop/Python/NewProject/data_analyst.py

Unfortunately, this isn't working.

any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

I googled this problem before, but the issue remain.

Comment: Please update your question with a full description of the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i don't think you can activate your virtual environment in the crontab file itself like that. you could put that in ~/.bashrc, or ~/.bash_profile, then run this alongwith your `data_analyst.py` file in the crontab